# Why does my list of tuples only have one entry?

Tags: python, function, tuples, arguments

I have a list of tuples I am using as an argument to a function. I want the function to randomly pick one of tuples in the list (I was using the random.randint, but commented it out for testing purposes) and return it. How could I change it where each entry in the list was a tuple instead of having one entry?

`announce_winner()` works fine. I just did not add it in.

```
def get_winner(*nominees):
# Should accept as nominees a list of items
    winner = nominees[0]
#[random.randint(1, range(nominees))]
    return winner
# Randomly pick one of the nominees (list items) as the winner
# Return the winner (list item) to the caller

def main():
    best_original_score_list = [('Terence Blanchard','Da 5 Bloods'),
                                ('Trent Reznor and Atticus Ross','Mank'),
                                ('Emile Mosseri','Minari'),
                                ('James Newton Howard','News of the World'),
                                ('Trent Reznor, Atticus Ross, and Jon Batiste','Soul')]
    announce_nominees('Best Original Score',best_original_score_list)
    winner = get_winner(best_original_score_list)

main()
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want. You pass in a list, and then you unpack that list in your argument definition. Is it possible the `*` there is just a typo?

Comment: "How could I change it where each entry in the list was a tuple instead of having one entry?" Each entry in the list **is** a tuple. I don't understand what the problem is. What are you expecting to happen when you run the code? How is that different from what actually happens?

Comment: There is no `announce_winner()` referenced in your code and the placement of comments is very confusing. Pleae provide an [mre].

Comment: To illustrate what @MarcusMüller is saying, consider a minimal example: try having just `def test(*args): print(args)` and then `test([])`. Notice how it does not print `[]`, but instead `([],)` (i.e., a tuple containing the list)? That's because of what the `*` in the argument list is doing, in order the handle a varying number of arguments. You don't want or need that here; take it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but if I understand what you are trying to accomplish the code below may show you the way. Specifically, if you want to pick one of the tuples randomly from `best_original_score_list` then pass in the list (no need to "tuple-fy" it using `*nominees`) then pick a random tuple in the list using the appropriate random function.

Example:

```
from random import randrange

def get_winner(nominees):
    winner = nominees[randrange(0, len(nominees))]
    return winner

def main():
    best_original_score_list = [('Terence Blanchard','Da 5 Bloods'),
                                ('Trent Reznor and Atticus Ross','Mank'),
                                ('Emile Mosseri','Minari'),
                                ('James Newton Howard','News of the World'),
                                ('Trent Reznor, Atticus Ross, and Jon Batiste','Soul')]

    winner = get_winner(best_original_score_list)
    print(winner)

main()
```

Output:

```
('Trent Reznor and Atticus Ross', 'Mank')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're actually looking at [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
def get_winner(nominees):
    return random.choice(nominees)

def main():
    best_original_score_list = [
        ('Terence Blanchard','Da 5 Bloods'),
        ('Trent Reznor and Atticus Ross','Mank'),
        ('Emile Mosseri','Minari'),
        ('James Newton Howard','News of the World'),
        ('Trent Reznor, Atticus Ross, and Jon Batiste','Soul'),
    ]
    announce_nominees('Best Original Score',best_original_score_list)
    winner = get_winner(best_original_score_list)

main()
```